# Get value of meta keyword

Tags: magento2

Hello guys I want to print meta keyword value of a product. How can I achive this? I tried this but It doesnt work :

```
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $_product = $_product->getMetaKeyword();
```

edit: OK guys I realized that I didnt get productid dynamically so I fixed the problem. Thank you guys!

Comment: in mageno1 or magento2?

Comment: as per the code he added m1 code , but added tag for m2 but i think he need code for m1

Comment: where you want to get meta keyword details ?

Comment: I need for m1. I need to show them on sitemap. I want to use value of metakeywords of products in sitemap. which is in  app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/SiteMap.php

htmlspecialchars($baseUrl . $item->getUrl() . "here I want metatag"),

Answer (score 3):

This one is working for me.

```
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2);
    echo $_product->getMetaKeyword();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Magento 1 :-**

```
  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('10'); //Product Id

  $metaKeywords = $_product->getData('meta_keywords');

  echo $metaKeywords;
```

**Magento 2 :-**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load('10'); //Product Id

$metaKeywords = $product->getMetaKeywords();

echo $metaKeywords
```

Answer (score 1):

How can I get productId in this loop?

```
foreach ($products->getItems() as $item) {
            $xml = sprintf(
                '<url><loc>%s</loc><lastmod>%s</lastmod><changefreq>%s</changefreq><priority>%.1f</priority></url>',
                htmlspecialchars($baseUrl . $item->getUrl() . ),
                $date,
                $changefreq,
                $priority
            );
            $io->streamWrite($xml);
        }
```

Comment: OK guys I found out. $item->getId()